# Prove: $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{S(x_0,\varepsilon)}u(x)\operatorname{grad}(\varphi(x))\cdot N\,ds=u(x_0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> For $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n,n\geq 3$, let $\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{(n-2)\omega_n}\cdot\frac{1}{\|x-x_0\|^{n-2}}$, where $\omega_n$ is the surface area of the sphere $S_{n-1}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n;\|x\|=1\}$.
>   Prove that, if $u\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
>   then:
>    $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{S(x_0,\varepsilon)}u(x) \operatorname{grad}(\varphi(x))\cdot N\,ds = u(x_0),$$
>
> where $S(x_0,\varepsilon)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\|x-x_0\|=\varepsilon\}$ and $N$ is internal normal vector.

Where can I find a proof to this? or in which theorem should I look?

Comment: The two big theorems relating surface integrals to other integrals are the Divergence Theorem and Stokes's Theorem.  Do either of those look fruitful?

Comment: I just realized you're not assuming $n=3$.  So one of those is not as applicable as the other.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang So it is related to Stokes?